# Why doesn't tooltip text appear for A tag

Tags: html, css, tooltip

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html lang=en>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <TITLE>favorite things</TITLE>
        <META name="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="filk">
        <style>
            p        {
                       text-indent:2em;
                     }
            p.drop   {
                       text-indent:0;
                     }
            p.drop::first-letter  {
                       font-size:2em;
                       text-indent:0;
                     }
            a.l,div.l,span.l {
                       display:inline;
                       float:left;
                       width:15%;
                       position:absolute;
                       left:-20%;
                     }
            a.r,div.r,span.r {
                       display:inline;
                       float:right;
                       width:15%;
                       position:absolute;
                       right:20%;
                     }
            h1       {
                       text-align:center;
                       font-size:4em;
                     }
            ul       {
                       text-indent:4em;
                     }

            <!--
            img.l    {
                       float:left;
                       width:999px;
                       max-width:15%;
                       position:absolute;
                       left:-20%;
                     }
            img.r    {
                       float:right;
                       width:15%;
                       position:absolute;
                       right:20%;
                     }
            -->
            img.v    {
                       display:block;
                       margin:10% 10% 10% 10%;
                       width:100%;
                     }

       /* Tooltip container */
      .tooltip {
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
      }

      /* Tooltip text */
      .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0;
        border-radius: 6px;

        /* Position the tooltip text */
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 125%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -40px;
        Min-width: 20em;
        max-width: 70em;

        /* Fade in tooltip */
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.3s;
      }

      /* Tooltip arrow */
      .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
      }

      /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
      .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
      }
            .verse   {
                       text-align: center; font-size: 2em; width:60%
                     }
        </style>
</head>
<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">
<H1>My favorite things</H1>
<div style="position:absolute; left:20%; width:60%; right:-20%;">

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silmarillion">
<img class=V src="../Images/Silmarillion.png"
             alt="The Silmarillion">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungoliant">Gardening spiders</a>
<br>
<a class=R href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring">
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring_cover.gif"
             alt="The Fellowship of the Ring">
</a>
And
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_weapons_and_armour#Narsil">
  swords that are broken
</a>
<br>
Words in the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech">Black Speech</a>
<br>
That must not be spoken
<br>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denethor">Unfaithful stewards</a>
<br>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_King">
<img class=V src="../Images/81UzbZbGPUL._SL1500_.jpg"
             alt="The Return of the King">
</a>
Who don't want their kings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[hook]
</p>
<p class="drop verse">
When the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orc">orc</a> bites,
<br>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Currents_of_Space">
<img class=V src="../Images/Currents_of_space.jpg"
             alt="The Currents of Space">
</a>
when the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Currents_of_Space">probe</a> stings
<br>
When I'm feeling bad
<br>
I simply remember
<br>
My favorite <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aragorn">kings</a>
<br>
And I don't feel so bad.
</p>
<div class=L>
             <!--
<img class=V src="../Images/ASF_0224.jpg"
             alt="Astounding Science Fiction vol. XLIII, no. 5, July 1949">
<img class=V src="../Images/ANLGOCT67.jpg"
             Alt="<i>Analog vol. 80,no 2, October 1967">
             -->
</div>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_of_Vega">
<img class=V src="../Images/Agent_of_vega.jpg"
             Alt="<i>Agent of Vega</i> front cover">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
Peddlers who drive their
<br>
Mysterious wagons
<br>
<a class=R href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonflight">
<img class=V src="../Images/AnneMcCaffrey_Dragonflight.jpg"
             Alt="<i>Dragonflight</i> front cover">
</a>
Petite young ladies
<br>
Who can speak to dragons
<br>
Travelling the Cosmos
<br>
In a
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang">ship who sings</a>
<span class=L>
<img class=V src="../Images/THSHPWHSNG681969.jpg"
             alt="The Ship Who Sang front cover">
</span>
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="drop verse">
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies">
   Time traveling bar men
   <span class=tooltiptext>
      &lsquo;&mdash;All You Zombies&mdash;&rsquo; from The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, March 1959
   </span>
</a>
<br>
<span class="L tooltip">
<img class=V src="../Images/FSFMar1959.jpg"
             alt="The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, March 1959">
   <span class=tooltiptext>
      The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, March 1959
   </span>
</span>
Who are like no others
<br>
Who are their own fathers
<br>
And are their own mothers
<br>
<a class=R href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein">
<img class=V src="../Images/Heinlein-face.jpg"
             alt="Robert Anson Heinlein, Grand Master of SF">
</a>
Of all such stories
<br>
Know <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein">Heinlein's</a> are kings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Darcy_(character)">
<img class=V src="../Images/0743435486-med.jpg"
             alt="Lord Darcy">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
A <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Darcy_(character)">ducal detective</a> whose
<br>
Aide does the magic
<br>
Finds that their cases
<br>
Are often quite tragic
<br>
I hope that more stories
<br>
still lurk in the wings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<div class=L>
             <!--
<img class=V src="../Images/md7993587667.jpg"
             alt="Analog vol. 75, no. 5, July 1965">
             -->
</div>
<p class="drop verse">
Oversized lizards
<br>
With partners named David
<br>
Who trade with sophonts
<br>
who sometimes are rabid
<br>
Finding new planets
<br>
With glorious rings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<div class=L>
             <!--
<img class=V src="../Images/tn_ASF_0408.jpg"
             alt="Analog, November 1964">
             -->
</div>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Kalvan_of_Otherwhen">
<img class=V src="../Images/LordKalvanOfOtherwhen.jpg"
             alt="Lord Kalvan of Otherwhen">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalvan_(Calvin_Morrison)">Calvin</a> who knows his
<br>
Military history
<br>
Runs afoul of the great
<br>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paratime_series">Paratime</a> mystery
<br>
The hand of a lovely
<br>
Young princess it brings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="drop verse">
Peasants are fleeing
<br>
'Till Kalvan take over
<br>
They win the fight but he's
<br>
Shot by his lover
<br>
A chance to win glory
<br>
And power it brings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<br>
<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="drop verse">
Some yell in terror
<br>
But he can yell louder
<br>
He teaches Prince
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_Characters_in_the_Kalvan_series#Prince_Ptosphes">
  Ptosphes
</a>
<br>
How to make gunpowder
<br>
To the priests of Styphon
<br>
A gauntlet he flings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<div class=L>
             <!--
<img class=V src="../Images/ASF_0420.jpg"
             alt="Analog, November 1965">
             -->
</div>
<p class="drop verse">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Kalvan_of_Otherwhen">
They thought they were lost but
</a>
<br>
Their <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Kalvan_of_Otherwhen">hopes</a> he's igniting
<br>
Yet he can't keep Rylla his
<br>
Love from the fighting
<br>
He is a rival
<br>
To all the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_Characters_in_the_Kalvan_series#Great_King_Kaiphranos">great kings</a>
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wizard_in_Rhyme">
<img class=V src="../Images/f200aeb40ef0df1c56b4f1ea9ebdb178.jpg"
             alt="Her Majesty's Wizard">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
Untenured scholars
<br>
Who feel they're in Hades
<br>
Rescue from prison
<br>
Deposed royal ladies
<br>
Summoning dragons
<br>
With tears in  their wings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Beautiful_Friendship_%28novel%29">
<img class=V src="../Images/0671319752-lg.jpg"
             alt="A Beautiful Friendship">
</a>
<a class=R href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Honor_of_the_Queen">
<img class=V src="../Images/TheHonorOfTheQueen.jpg"
             alt="The Honor of The Queen">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
Small gentle <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Beautiful_Friendship_(novel)">treecats</a>
<br>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_characters_in_the_Honorverse#Winton-Henke,_Anson_to_Wright">
With friends that are royal
</a>
<br>
Humans with treecats
<br>
To whom they are loyal
<br>
Mess with their two legs
<br>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Honor_of_the_Queen">
And see what that brings
</a>
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shards_of_Honor">
<img class=V src="../Images/9781625793980-med.jpg"
             alt="Shards of Honor">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shards_of_Honor">
Betan survey ships
</a>
<br>
Whose captains are taken
<br>
Vorbarran warships
<br>
That with strife are shaken
<br>
Mess with <a href="https://vorkosigan.fandom.com/wiki/Cordelia_Naismith_Vorkosigan">
  Cordellia
</a>
<br>
A slit throat she brings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrayar">
<img class=V src="../Images/9781625793959-lg.jpg"
             alt="Barrayar">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrayar">Stealing</a> the
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Vorkosigan">
  son
</a>
of
<br>
A
<a href="https://vorkosigan.fandom.com/wiki/Cordelia_Naismith_Vorkosigan">
  helpless Vor Lady
</a>
<br>
Who has an
<a href="https://vorkosigan.fandom.com/wiki/Konstantine_Bothari">
  armsman
</a>
<br>
Who is rather shady
<br>
<a href="https://vorkosigan.fandom.com/wiki/Vidal_Vordarian">
  Losing your head
</a>
is
<br>
The fate that it brings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_Wrede#Magic_and_Malice">
<img class=V src="../Images/Mairelon_the_Magician_.jpg"
             alt="Mairelon the Magician">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
Thieves dressed as boys
<br>
Who are caught and coopted
<br>
Help solve a case
<br>
And wind up adopted
<br>
Hide behind the table
<br>
When a foe magic flings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_Wrede#Magic_and_Malice">
<img class=V src="../Images/169885._SY475_.jpg"
             alt="Magician's Ward">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
Students of magic
<br>
Weighed down by their reading
<br>
Who their decorum
<br>
Not always are heeding
<br>
Rescue their teacher
<br>
And get wedding rings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Civil_Campaign">
<img class=V src="../Images/0671578855-lg.jpg"
             alt="A Civil Campaign">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Civil_Campaign">Bungled proposals</a> can
<br>
Sometimes be tricky
<br>
You'll face his <a href="https://vorkosigan.fandom.com/wiki/Ekaterin_Nile_Vorkosigan">mother</a>
<br>
When you mess with <a href="https://vorkosigan.fandom.com/wiki/Nikolai_Vorsoisson">Nikki</a>
<br>
She's a strong lady
<br>
Who knows a few things
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="drop verse">
Gullible inlaws
<br>
Want to take Nicholai
<br>
Emperor Gregor
<br>
Responds to his outcry
<br>
Meddlesome shavetails
<br>
The
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Vorkosigan_Saga_characters#Barrayarans">
  emperor
</a>
zings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>

<br>
<p>

[Verse]
</p>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorverse#Crown_of_Slaves_series">
<img class=V src="../Images/0671319752-med.jpg"
             alt="Changer of Worlds: From the Highlands">
</a>
<p class="drop verse">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_characters_in_the_Honorverse#X,_Isaac_to_X,_Jeremy">Audobon dancers</a> who
<br>
Will not be chattels
<br>
Have strange bedfellows
<br>
To help with their battles
<br>
With secret agents
<br>
They sometimes have flings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to display a text balloon when the cursor is over certain images and text, I found some mouseover CSS on the web, and modified it for my purposes, My CSS does what I want when I move the cursor over text and images inside DIV and SPAN elements, but not for hyperlinks in an A tag. It does, however work for an A tag inside a SPAN with CLASS=TOOLTIP

```
    <style>
        p        {
                   text-indent:2em;
                 }
        p.drop   {
                   text-indent:0;
                 }
        p.drop::first-letter  {
                   font-size:2em;
                   text-indent:0;
                 }
        a.l,div.l,span.l {
                   display:inline;
                   float:left;
                   width:15%;
                   position:absolute;
                   left:-20%;
                 }
        a.r,div.r,span.r {
                   display:inline;
                   float:right;
                   width:15%;
                   position:absolute;
                   right:20%;
                 }
        h1       {
                   text-align:center;
                   font-size:4em;
                 }
        ul       {
                   text-indent:4em;
                 }

        <!--
        img.l    {
                   float:left;
                   width:999px;
                   max-width:15%;
                   position:absolute;
                   left:-20%;
                 }
        img.r    {
                   float:right;
                   width:15%;
                   position:absolute;
                   right:20%;
                 }
        -->
        img.v    {
                   display:block;
                   margin:10% 10% 10% 10%;
                   width:100%;
                 }

   /* Tooltip container */
  .tooltip {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
  }

  /* Tooltip text */
  .tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

    /* Position the tooltip text */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    Min-width: 20em;
    max-width: 70em;

    /* Fade in tooltip */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
  }

  /* Tooltip arrow */
  .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
  }

  /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
  .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
        .verse   {
                   text-align: center; font-size: 2em; width:60%
                 }
    </style>
```

```
<p class="drop verse">
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies">
   Time traveling bar men
   <span class=tooltiptext>
      &lsquo;&mdash;All You Zombies&mdash;&rsquo; from The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, March 1959
   </span>
</a>
<br>
<span class="L tooltip">
<img class=V src="../Images/FSFMar1959.jpg"
             alt="The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, March 1959">
   <span class=tooltiptext>
      The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, March 1959
   </span>
</span>
Who are like no others
<br>
Who are their own fathers
<br>
And are their own mothers
<br>
<a class=R href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein">
<img class=V src="../Images/Heinlein-face.jpg"
             alt="Robert Anson Heinlein, Grand Master of SF">
</a>
Of all such stories
<br>
Know <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein">Heinlein's</a> are kings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
```

I got the tooltip for the image, but not for the text "Time traveling bar men".

Changing tooltptext to `display:sticky;` let me get the tooltip, but introduced extraneous blank lines and border.

Comment: It would be great to put your code into a running example with a [Stackoverflow snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or to put it on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can debug it.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is an the positioning of your `.tooltiptext`:

```css
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /* Position the tooltip text */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    min-width: 20em;
    max-width: 70em;
    /* Fade in tooltip */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
```

Especially `bottom: 125%;` which makes it leave the screen.

Comment: Isn't  that supposed to be relative to the containing element rather than the entire screen?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is due to HTML's scope rules. The solution was to remove the positioning information from <div>, add it to the style for <p>, with display:relative, and move every tag with class=tooltip inside a <p></p>.

```
<style>
    p        {
               left:20%;
               position:relative;
               right:-20%;
               text-indent:2em;
               width:60%;
             }
    p.drop   {
               text-indent:0;
             }
    p.drop::first-letter  {
               font-size:2em;
               text-indent:0;
             }
    a.L,div.L,span.L {
               display:inline;
               width:14%;
               position:absolute;
               left:-20%;
             }
    a.R,div.R,span.R {
               display:inline;
               width:14%;
               position:absolute;
               right:00%;
             }
    h1       {
               text-align:center;
               font-size:4em;
             }
    ul       {
               text-indent:4em;
             }

    <!--
    img.L    {
               width:999px;
               max-width:15%;
               position:absolute;
               left:-20%;
             }
    img.R    {
               width:15%;
               position:absolute;
               right:20%;
             }
    -->
    img.V    {
               display:block;
               margin:10% 10% 10% 10%;
               max-width:100;
               max-height:auto;
               width:100%;
             }

   /* Tooltip container */
  .tooltip {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
  }

  /* Commented out becaus it messes up formatting */
  <!--
  span.tooltip {
    display:inline-block;
  }
  -->

  /* Tooltip text */
  .tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

    /* Position the tooltip text */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 110%;
    left: 10%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    Min-width: 20em;
    max-width: 70em;

    /* Fade in tooltip */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
  }

  /* Tooltip arrow */
  .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
  }

  /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
  .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .verse     {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    width:60%
  }
</style>
```